# ScannerとBufferedReaderの違いについて

Tags: java

Aizu Online ジャッジというサイトのこの問題(http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_4_D)
を解いています。

以下のコードを提出するとRuntime errorになってしまうのですが、どこが間違っているか教えてください。

標準入力を2行ともBufferedReaderで取得すれば成功するのですが、1行目をScanner、2行目をBufferedReaderで取得するとRuntime errorになります。
Scannerが何かいけないような気はするのですが、どういう問題が発生しているのかよくわかりません。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try{
            int n=scan.nextInt();
            String s=reader.readLine();
            String[] str =s.split(" ");
            int array_num[]= new int[n];
            long max, min, sum;
            sum=0;
            max=-1000000;
            min=1000000;

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                array_num[i]=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                sum+=array_num[i];

                if(array_num[i]>max)max=array_num[i];
                if(array_num[i]<min)min=array_num[i];
            }

            System.out.println(min+" "+max+" "+sum);



            scan.close();
            reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("エラー:"+e);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 具体的な Runtime error の内容を書くと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一般的に、ひとつの入力 (`System.in`) を包む形で処理するオブジェクトを、２つ生成するのはコード的にとても怪しい感じがします。

実際に調べてみたところ、 `Scanner` は内部で `InputStreamReader` を利用していますがこ、これについては [公式ドキュメント](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) より、

> To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes
>   may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to
>   satisfy the current read operation.

なので、少なくとも `Scanner` を利用したら、他の経路で同一の`System.in`を読み込むのは避けた方がいいと思います。

---

なので、今回のケースでは、最初の scanner の結果分だけ、 for 文で `nextInt`するのがいいのではないでしょうか。